# How to do softmax for pixelwise classification

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, pytorch

My goal is to do grey scale image segmentation using pixelwise classification. So I have two labels 0 and 1. I made a network in pytorch which looks like the following.

```python
class Net(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()

    self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')

    self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(256, 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  



def forward(self, x):
    in_size = x.size(0)

    x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv13(x))

    x = F.softmax(x, 2)

    return x
```

In the last layer I designed the conv13 in such that it produces 2 channels one for each class.

Since I was using the softmax I was expecting that summation of value of same index on 2 separate channel would equal to 1.

For example assume the output image is ( 2{channel}, 4, 4). So I was expecting that

> image[ channel 1 ][0][0] + image[ channel 2 ][0][0] = 1

But the output I get is 0.0015 which is not even close to 1. How can i use the softmax to predict channelwise ?

To check this I used the following code

```python
for batch, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    inputs , labels = data
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)


    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = rmse(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    running_loss += loss.item()


    predicted = outputs.data
    predicted = predicted.to('cpu')
    predicted_img = predicted.numpy()

    predicted_img = np.reshape(predicted_img,(2, 4, 4))

    print(predicted_img[0])
    print(predicted_img[1])
```

Those prints showed this

`[[**0.2762002**  0.13305853 0.2510342  0.23114938]
 [0.26812425 0.28500515 0.05682982 0.15851443]
 [0.1640967  0.5409352  0.43547812 0.44782472]
 [0.29157883 0.0410011  0.2566578  0.16251141]]`

`[[**0.23052207** 0.868455   0.43436486 0.0684725 ]
 [0.18001427 0.02341573 0.0727293  0.2525512 ]
 [0.06587404 0.04974682 0.3773188  0.6559266 ]
 [0.5235896  0.05838248 0.11558701 0.02304965]]`

It is clear that the corresponding elements are not summing up to 1 like

> 0.2762002 (index 0, 0) + 0.23052207 (index 0, 0) != 1

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Why have both tensorflow and pytorch tags?

Comment: edited ! It seems stackoverflow automatically suggested the tag tensorflow and I prematurely submitted the question without removing it  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check last line of my code .. basically your dimension for softmax was wrong.

```
class Net(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')

        self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(256, 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  



    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)

        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv13(x))

        x = F.softmax(x, 1) #this line is changed

        return x

net = Net()
inputs = torch.rand(1,1,4,4)
out = net (Variable(inputs))
print (out)
out.sum(dim=1)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Basically I figured that out a just little while ago. I was giving F.softmax(x, 2)  2 for 2 classes. But then realized that the parameter asked on which dimension to perform softmax, it doesnt ask for the number of classes. Since I want it to span across the channels the value would be 1 as the torch tensors are shaped liked [ batch, channel , height, width ].